# Original OS For Samsung Galaxy S I9000

Tags: restore, stock-android, samsung-galaxy-s

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I put a ROM on my Samsung Galaxy S I9000 and now it doesn't fully work.  I was wondering if there was a way to get the original ROM, that came with my device, from an official site somewhere.  I was told that apparently you can do it on the Android site, but I can't see any place to do that.

Comment: We need more information, including the ROM that you put on your phone and the method that you used to do so.

Comment: Ideally, you would make a nandroid backup before you flashed a new rom.  Did you do this?

Answer (score 5):

Go to [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=846913) and download the newest firmware for your region.  Download [Odin for Windows](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=9088113&postcount=1) (search for "Heimdall" if you are on Linux).  Then do the following:

1. [Put your phone into Download mode](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/index.php?title=Samsung_Galaxy_S_Series#Download_Mode)

   1. Remove the battery
   2. Hold VolumeDown plus the Home key

      1. Reinsert the battery.
      2. Let go of the power button only about 1 second after the white device logo appears (if it does)
      3. After a few seconds a yellow triangle with an android in it should appear, you can let go of the keys since this is download mode.
2. Start up Odin.
3. Attach the phone to USB so that Odin recognizes it.  If it doesn't, reboot your phone, exit Odin, and go back to step (1).
4. Load the .zip file you downloaded (the custom ROM) into the PDA field of Odin.
5. Load the 512 .pit file into the PIT field of Odin.
6. Check "Re-partition".
7. Hit Start.  Odin will tell you when it's done; if it fails, reboot your phone and try again.  (This happens occasionally).

Note that if you need to back anything up, you should do that beforehand and save the backup to your PC, since everything (except probably the external SD card) will be wiped on the phone.  Also note that you do this at your own risk; Odin is very powerful and misusing it can damage your phone.  Re-partition in particular can be troublesome if you select the wrong PIT file.  I've used Odin dozens of times myself safely, though.

Answer (score 0):

The [Samsung Galaxy S](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S) shipped with OS 2.1 / Eclair so that's probably what you want to restore it to.

Without knowing how you installed the new OS (i.e. what steps did you follow?) and what isn't working now, it's hard to troubleshoot, but you ought to be able to get the original OS from Samsung support. I don't see the S i9000 on the US site, but you're perhaps not in the US?

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to get Android OS:

1. You can download a leaked ROM, e.g. for [SGS i9000](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/03/27/official-android-2-3-gingerbread-rom-leaked-for-samsung-galaxy-s-i9000/).
2. You can download from the source code from [official repository](http://source.android.com), search/write drivers, and compile yourself.
3. Modded ROMs. There are many custom ROMs for Android, the most popular includes CyanogenMod, MIUI, etc.

I'd suggest #1 or #3, they're usually much less work since the drivers are already there and manufacturer's/custom ROM can often better utilize the phone's unique capability than the generic ROM you compile from source code (unless your device is of the Nexus-series).

Answer (score 0):

Original ROMs are hosted on http://samfirmware.com

This isn't an official repository - rather, it's a community supported repository of official ROMs